# Шрифт и кодировка

Tags: кодировка, шрифты

например шрифт Arial, ищу в поисковике открывается таблица с символами, так же пробиваю кодировка (например utf-8) и вижу тоже таблица символами, так какая между ними разница?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шрифт - как нарисована буква, это графическое изображение символа.

Кодировка - как буквы представлены в двоичном формате.

Например, в кодировке ASCII код 0x41 обозначает латинскую букву "A". Но как эта "А" будет отображаться на экране/бумаге, зависит от выбранного шрифта.

В таблице со шрифтом Arial есть только буквы, тогда как в таблице с любой кодировкой будут еще и их десятичные/восьмеричные коды, без которых такая таблица не имеет смысла.